# Android how to kill previous application instance while launching new instance

Tags: android, process, state, launching-application, android-launcher

i have used android:launchMode="singleInstance", it stops from creating another instance of the application while preserves the first instance.

here's my activity's configuration info

```
<activity
        android:name="com.abc.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ABC"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="192.168.0.52"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: You claim to have used it, but your configuration doesn't seem to have it!

Comment: that's what i'm using ! is it debuggable as it is launched from some external sourcelink ?                                                if (!isTaskRoot()) {
       final Intent intent = getIntent();
       final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
       if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)&&intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE) &&
               intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)) {
           finish();
       }
   }

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're trying to restart your app. You can do that by setting an alarm in the near future to start your app and in the meantime kill the existing process.

That can be achieved with the following code:

```
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) MyActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, PendingIntent.getActivity(MyActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyActivity.class), 0));
android.os.Process.sendSignal(android.os.Process.myPid(), android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);
```

Comment: but both the instances carry different app data. say instanceA carry Bob's info from sourcelinkA. if app get launched from sourcelinkB which initializes the instanceB that carries Foo's info then in that case the app should launch itself with Foo's info and the instanceA which contains Bob's info should finish itself.

Answer (score 2):

`android:launchMode="singleInstance"` is for an activity and not for application/process. It doesn't preserve the first instance. It makes sure there is only one instance. Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html) carefully.

If you want to kill your activity, you should call `finish()`